# Pass NULL from powershell to sql

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to pass a NULL from powershell to sql, without having to write NULL in the VALUES. For example below, i've tried so many things and can't get it to work, any ideas? Writing VALUES (NULL,'4') will be too much hassle.

```
$a = $null
$SqlQuery2 = @"
USE Testtable INSERT INTO dbo.Test2
(name,ID)
VALUES ('$a','4')
"@
$sqlcmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($SqlQuery2,$global:sqlconn)
$sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

Comment: If your databse allows nulls, you can simply remove the column 'Name' and don't pass a value. It will insert a null value in SQL.
`USE Testtable INSERT INTO dbo.Test2 (ID) VALUES ('4')`

Comment: If you don't want to use `NULL` in the query, how should the database determine that you want to use it?

Comment: the values element has around 100 different columns/values so wanted a quick easy win if that was possible..

Comment: The only way i can see is to not pass the powershell parameter for sql value in the script. Would be less hassle to just run batch script against the DB replacing any empty strings with NULL, or run this immediately after each insert command to fix the issue

Comment: Do not build SQL queries the way you do, otherwise you could be facing a [quick loss](https://xkcd.com/327/) due to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).